# profile sync daemon crontab necessary?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sync, cron

I'm running ubuntu 22.04 and installed profile-sync-daemon. The configuration was pretty easy by simply using the defaults and activating the daemon:

```
systemctl --user start psd
systemctl --user status psd
systemctl --user enable psd
psd preview
```

On my personal notes from back in the days I mentioned editing "crontab -e" by adding the following lines:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/profile-sync-daemon sync &>/dev/null
```

My guess is, that this is not necessary anymore, because the sync happens automatically with systemd's timer (probably). Also psd's man page does not mention, that such configuration is needed, so my guess is that syncing via crontab is indeed obsolete.

Can somebody confirm my guesses?